# C# Работа с коллекцией

Tags: c#

Как можно сделать вывод всей коллекции с определенного элемента ?
Допустим у меня есть коллекциия List boxes  в  ней содержится 10 элементов , в Box есть свойство int Number.
Допустим нашел совпадающее свойство в boxes[3] , я хочу через цикл foreach перебрать всю коллекцию начиная с boxes[3] заканчивая boxes[2] . То есть он перебирал так:

boxes[3] => boxes[4] => boxes[5] => boxes[6] => boxes[7] => boxes[8] => boxes[9] => boxes[0] => boxes[1] => boxes[2].

Comment: `foreach` - это перебор всех элементов коллекции. Для перебора промежутка коллекции - используй `for (;;)`

Comment: Ещё `LINQ` есть - `Skip(...)` и т.д. Там можно и с `foreach`

Comment: "Допустим у меня есть коллекция List boxes в ней содержится 10 элементов , в Box есть свойство int Number. Допустим нашел совпадающее свойство в boxes[3]". Что это значит? Я не понимаю как это относится к перебору. Сформулируй вопрос более понятно.

Comment: Я бы сделал два простых цикла `for` и не парился. Первый, начиная с индекса 3 до конца, второй - с нуля до индекса 3. Просто, быстро, эффективно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var boxes = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

foreach (var box in boxes.SkipWhile(b => b != 3).Concat(boxes.TakeWhile(b => b != 3)))
    Console.WriteLine(box);
```

Вывод

```
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
2
```

Comment: Спасибо ... Вы гуру ))

Comment: На здоровье! Если помогло, то галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: @eswcpoker про галочку (тагнуть забыли автора)

Comment: Помогло ... Галочка ваша ))